# Checkbox uncheck if other checkbox is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have many city input checkboxes. I have given the first checkbox the name **All**; if the user selects that then only **All** checkbox gets selected, and not the other city checkboxes.

If the user checks any other city, then the **All** checkbox should automatically be unchecked. I want to do this with JavaScript or jQuery.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="city_pref[]" id="city_all" value="0" checked /><label for="city_all">All</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="city_pref[]" id="city_pref_1" value="Chicago" /><label for="city_pref_1">Chicago</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="city_pref[]" id="city_pref_2" value="Texas" /><label for="city_pref_2">Texas</label>
```

and so on....

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: i apologize, but i searched google for the similar solution, but wasn't able to find that.

Comment: Sometimes there are things that you won't find on Google. Either because you didn't search correctly or because nobody has implemented them yet. In this case you could try to implement it yourself. It is about this implementation that I was asking. What code did you already  write in attempt to solve this problem? What difficulties did you encounter with this code? Because on Stack Overflow we would be more than happy to help you if you show some efforts and not just ask for someone giving you teh codez which is how I interpret your question at its present form.

Comment: I've run into issues where I haven't had anything similar, and can't really even formulate a "plan of attack."  It sounds like he just hasn't dealt with this before, and therefore has no clue where to start.  So if you want to attempt it yourself, the way I'd do it would be to count the number of checked boxes and if it's zero check the all box, otherwise have it uncheck itself.  Start googling things like "count child checkboxes checked jquery" and "check checkbox jquery" (hint, check the first results).  Or he's just lazy xD

Comment: @mazzzzz - the first case, I think. Although I tend to support the 'what have you tried' meme here, it occurs to me of late that breaking a problem down into component parts, and knowing what to search for, is a lot more non-trivial than we often give it credit for.

Comment: @halfer Definitely, it's simple after you've done it a few times.  jQuery (imo) takes a different way of thinking than other languages (me coming from PHP to learn jQuery was interesting).  But after you get your head wrapped around the paradigm it becomes easier to just google it.

Comment: Mohan - you've not downvoted any of these answers, have you? I'd recommend not downvoting anything on any own questions, unless those answers are genuinely terrible; the downvoted items here look pretty helpful to me, even if they're not quite what you're after.

Comment: Ah, I wonder if someone has downvoted on the basis that some prior research could be required before helping. That would explain why my response, which was only guidance, didn't get a similar downvote.

Comment: @halfer Why the hunting for the down voter? People are allowed to do vote as they please without being punished for it. As for me, I think most answers here have low quality. Just throwing out code with no explanation of what it does, how it achieves it etc. that can be of help for others.

Comment: @Matsemann - it's not about punishment. As is clear from some of the answers on this page, people who've taken the time to add a working reply just have to guess why they've been downvoted, which is not constructive.

Comment: @halfer: I have not  downvoted anyone. I respect everyone's time, who are helping me here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
​$(function(){
    var el=$('input:checkbox[name="city_pref[]"]');
    el.on('change', function(e){
        if($(this).is(':checked')) el.not($(this)).prop('checked', false);
    });
});​
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/bGwrS/1/)

**Update:** (after the clarification of question)

```
$(function(){
    var el=$('input:checkbox[name="city_pref[]"]');
    el.on('change', function(e){
        if($(this).attr('id')!='city_all')
        {
            if($(this).is(':checked')) $('#city_all').prop('checked', false);
        }
        else
        {
            if($(this).is(':checked')) el.not($(this)).prop('checked', false);
        }
    });
});​
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/bGwrS/2/)

**Update:(23-07-2012)**

`I want the functionality, when no checkbox is selected, then All will get selected automatically`

[**Updated Demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/bGwrS/30/)

Comment: oops, i think, i did not clarify. i want checkbox to be multiselected except the case in "All".

Comment: +1 for a very helpful answer, although personally I think you might have left the clarification "as an exercise for the reader" `:)`

Comment: Hi Sheikh, can you please help me with one more thing in your latest fiddle, I want the functionality, when no checkbox is selected, then **All** will get selected automatically. Thanks.

Comment: [Check this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/bGwrS/29/).

Answer (score 2):

Darin's right - although it would be a good idea for someone to give you some tips on *how* to solve this problem. If I read the question correctly, the only dynamic behaviour you want is when someone ticks a box which is not "All"; in this case, you want the "All" box unticked.

OK, so you need to break the problem down into pieces. Here's what I'd do:

- Attach a function to all controls that are not "All". I'd do this with a class selector, but equally you could do the "not name" approach (as per Yograj Gupta's answer)
- Inside the event handler, have an `if` statement that only runs if the control is found to be ticked (i.e. if "All" is selected and you *untick* a city, nothing happens).
- If the `if` statement runs, untick the "All" control

Each of those items are now small enough that the jQuery docs can be consulted. In this case of course you have some ready-made solutions, but the approach of breaking problems down is very important if you want to self-improve as a programmer.

Addendum: also - and a good tip for forum questions generally - if you find an answer gets you 80% of the way to your requirements, try to implement the other 20% yourself. I agree it's not always possible, since everyone has to ask for help sometimes, but it's good practice that in the long run you'll find helps the learning process.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/xRjke/1/)**

```
$('#city_all').change(function(){   
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
       $('input:checkbox[name^=city_pref]').attr('checked','checked'); 
    else
        $('input:checkbox[name^=city_pref]').removeAttr('checked'); 
});

$('input:checkbox[name^=city_pref]').change(function(){    
    if($('input:checkbox[name^=city_pref]').not(':checked').length > 0)
        $('#city_all').removeAttr('checked'); 
    else
        $('#city_all').attr('checked','checked'); 
});
```

Note: To separate the other and all from the cities give them different name.
    ​

Answer (score 0):

Even though you should try to implement your own code first before asking for help, I think is fair to help someone who doesn't really know how to start doing something. So, I made this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/menislici/EMfcg/)

```
<input type="checkbox" class="all">all</input>
<input type="checkbox" name="city" class="london city">london</input>
<input type="checkbox" name="city" class="rome city">rome</input>
<input type="checkbox" name="city" class="tokio city">tokio</input>


 $('.all').click(function(){

 $('input[name=city]').attr("checked", true)

     })

     $('.city').click(function(){

         $('input[type=checkbox]').attr("checked", false)


         $(this).attr("checked", true)                      

     })
```

​

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('input:checkbox[name^=city_pref]').click(function(){
    if(this.id =="city_all"){
        $(this).siblings("input:checkbox").attr('checked',false);
    }
    else{
        $('#city_all').attr('checked',false);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll throw mine in here

```
$(function () {
    $('.checkbox-all .all').attr('disabled', true); //comment out if you want them to be able to toggle the all checkbox, but their input would be overwritten so I just disable it.

    $('.checkbox-all input[type="checkbox"]').change (function () {
        var numSelected = $(this).parent().children(':checked:not(.all)').length;
        $(this).siblings('.all').attr('checked', (numSelected == 0));
    });
});
```

With the HTML:

```
<div class="checkbox-all">
    <input class="all" type="checkbox" name="city_pref[]" id="city_all" value="0" checked /> <label for="city_all">All</label><br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="city_pref[]" id="city_pref_1" value="Chicago" /> <label for="city_pref_1">Chicago</label><br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="city_pref[]" id="city_pref_2" value="Texas" /> <label for="city_pref_2">Texas</label>
</div>
```

FYI, your `label` elements are set incorrectly in your example, I've set the `for` attributes correctly in my HTML.